# New question template keeps suggesting tag that is already added

Tags: bug, tags, ask-question-form

See:

[image]

The `git` tag is added, but it keeps being suggested.

---

Add 30/11:

I also see this now with the `python` tag:

[image]

Comment: Must be special case, because of git. The tag has been modified, but it's not staged for commit...

Comment: Duplicate on the uber-Meta: [Don't suggest tags that a question has already been tagged with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183620/dont-suggest-tags-that-a-question-has-already-been-tagged-with)

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure it's a duplicate of that one. Tags are not greyed out in this case.

Comment: I was asked to remove the status-review tag since it couldn't be reproduced and since it looked like a duplicate of some older tickets. If that's not the case feel free to retag as status-review with details and screenshots of the bug you're seeing and we'll look into it.